# Link docker containers in the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jaeger

I have a [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.19/getting-started/) running in a docker container in my local machine.

I've created a sample app which sends trace data to Jaeger. When running from the IDE, the data is sent perfectly.

I've containerized my app, and now I'm deploying it as a container, but the communication only works when I use `--link jaeger` to link both containers (expected).

My question is:

Is there a way of adding the `--link` parameter within my Dockerfile, so then I don't need to specify it when running the `docker run` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possibility of doing it in the Dockerfile if you want to keep two separate image. How should you know in advance the name/id of the container you're going to link ?

Below are two solutions :

1. Use Docker compose. This way, Docker will automatically link all the containers together
2. Create a `bridge` network and add all the container you want to link inside. This way, you'll have name resolution and you'll be able to contact each container using its name

Comment: I just want to add that using container names as hostnames only works on custom Docker bridged networks. The default one does not support this feature (as a security precaution).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using [netwoking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/), by creating:

```
docker network create [OPTIONS] NETWORK
```

and then run with --network="network"
using docker-compose with [network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#multi-host-networking) and link to each other
example:

```
  version: '3'
    services:
      jaeger:
       network:
        -network1
      other_container:
        network:
         -network1
    networks:
      network1:
        external: true
```